# How can I group by id in a array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, key, key-value

My data array like this :

```
let dataHospital = {
    availability: [
        {
            hosp_id: "1",
            hosp_name: "Hospital A",
            is_available: true
        },
        {
            hosp_id: "2",
            hosp_name: "Hospital B",
            is_available: false
        },
        {
            hosp_id: "3",
            hosp_name: "Hospital C",
            is_available: true
        }
    ],
    schedule: [
        {
            schedule_id: "xx1",
            hospital_id: "1",
            day: 1,
            from_time: "09:00:00",
            to_time: "13:00:00",
            hospital_name: "Hospital A",
        },
        {
            schedule_id: "xx2",
            hospital_id: "1",
            day: 2,
            from_time: "13:00:00",
            to_time: "20:00:00",
            hospital_name: "Hospital A"
        },
        {
            schedule_id: "xx3",
            hospital_id: "1",
            day: 3,
            from_time: "12:00:00",
            to_time: "23:00:00",
            hospital_name: "Hospital A"
        },
        {
            schedule_id: "xx4",
            hospital_id: "1",
            day: 4,
            from_time: "13:00:00",
            to_time: "16:00:00",
            hospital_name: "Hospital A"
        },
        {
            schedule_id: "xx5",
            hospital_id: "1",
            day: 5,
            from_time: "09:00:00",
            to_time: "13:00:00",
            hospital_name: "Hospital A"
        },
        {
            schedule_id: "xx6",
            hospital_id: "1",
            day: 6,
            from_time: "09:00:00",
            to_time: "18:00:00",
            hospital_name: "Hospital A"
        },
        {
            schedule_id: "xx7",
            hospital_id: "2",
            day: 1,
            from_time: "10:00:00",
            to_time: "14:00:00",
            hospital_name: "Hospital B"
        },
        {
            schedule_id: "xx8",
            hospital_id: "2",
            day: 2,
            from_time: "10:00:00",
            to_time: "14:00:00",
            hospital_name: "Hospital B"
        },
        {
            schedule_id: "xx9",
            hospital_id: "2",
            day: 2,
            from_time: "16:00:00",
            to_time: "18:00:00",             
            hospital_name: "Hospital B"
        },
        {
            schedule_id: "xx10",
            hospital_id: "2",
            day: 3,
            from_time: "10:00:00",
            to_time: "14:00:00",
            hospital_name: "Hospital B"
        },
        {
            schedule_id: "xx11",
            hospital_id: "2",
            day: 3,
            from_time: "16:00:00",
            to_time: "18:00:00",
            hospital_name: "Hospital B"
        },
        {
            schedule_id: "xx12",
            hospital_id: "2",
            day: 4,
            from_time: "08:00:00",
            to_time: "10:00:00",
            hospital_name: "Hospital B"
        },
        {
            schedule_id: "xx13",
            hospital_id: "2",
            day: 5,
            from_time: "10:00:00",
            to_time: "14:00:00",
            hospital_name: "Hospital B"
        },
        {
            schedule_id: "xx14",
            hospital_id: "2",
            day: 6,
            from_time: "10:00:00",
            to_time: "14:00:00",
            hospital_name: "Hospital B"
        },
        {
            schedule_id: "xx15",
            hospital_id: "3",
            day: 1,
            from_time: "15:00:00",
            to_time: "17:00:00",
            hospital_name: "Hospital C"
        },
        {
            schedule_id: "xx16",
            hospital_id: "3",
            day: 4,
            from_time: "15:00:00",
            to_time: "17:00:00",
            hospital_name: "Hospital C"
        },
        {
            schedule_id: "xx17",
            hospital_id: "3",
            day: 5,
            from_time: "15:00:00",
            to_time: "17:00:00",
            hospital_name: "Hospital C",
        }
    ]
}
```

So I have data array like that. I want to change the array like this :

```
let dataNewHospital = [
    {
        hosp_id: "1",
        hosp_name: "Hospital A",
        is_available: true,
        schedule: [
            {
                schedule_id: "xx1",
                hospital_id: "1",
                day: 1,
                from_time: "09:00:00",
                to_time: "13:00:00",
                hospital_name: "Hospital A",
            },
            {
                schedule_id: "xx2",
                hospital_id: "1",
                day: 2,
                from_time: "13:00:00",
                to_time: "20:00:00",
                hospital_name: "Hospital A"
            },
            {
                schedule_id: "xx3",
                hospital_id: "1",
                day: 3,
                from_time: "12:00:00",
                to_time: "23:00:00",
                hospital_name: "Hospital A"
            },
            {
                schedule_id: "xx4",
                hospital_id: "1",
                day: 4,
                from_time: "13:00:00",
                to_time: "16:00:00",
                hospital_name: "Hospital A"
            },
            {
                schedule_id: "xx5",
                hospital_id: "1",
                day: 5,
                from_time: "09:00:00",
                to_time: "13:00:00",
                hospital_name: "Hospital A"
            },
            {
                schedule_id: "xx6",
                hospital_id: "1",
                day: 6,
                from_time: "09:00:00",
                to_time: "18:00:00",
                hospital_name: "Hospital A"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        hosp_id: "2",
        hosp_name: "Hospital B",
        is_available: false,
        schedule: [
            {
                schedule_id: "xx7",
                hospital_id: "2",
                day: 1,
                from_time: "10:00:00",
                to_time: "14:00:00",
                hospital_name: "Hospital B"
            },
            {
                schedule_id: "xx8",
                hospital_id: "2",
                day: 2,
                from_time: "10:00:00",
                to_time: "14:00:00",
                hospital_name: "Hospital B"
            },
            {
                schedule_id: "xx9",
                hospital_id: "2",
                day: 2,
                from_time: "16:00:00",
                to_time: "18:00:00",             
                hospital_name: "Hospital B"
            },
            {
                schedule_id: "xx10",
                hospital_id: "2",
                day: 3,
                from_time: "10:00:00",
                to_time: "14:00:00",
                hospital_name: "Hospital B"
            },
            {
                schedule_id: "xx11",
                hospital_id: "2",
                day: 3,
                from_time: "16:00:00",
                to_time: "18:00:00",
                hospital_name: "Hospital B"
            },
            {
                schedule_id: "xx12",
                hospital_id: "2",
                day: 4,
                from_time: "08:00:00",
                to_time: "10:00:00",
                hospital_name: "Hospital B"
            },
            {
                schedule_id: "xx13",
                hospital_id: "2",
                day: 5,
                from_time: "10:00:00",
                to_time: "14:00:00",
                hospital_name: "Hospital B"
            },
            {
                schedule_id: "xx14",
                hospital_id: "2",
                day: 6,
                from_time: "10:00:00",
                to_time: "14:00:00",
                hospital_name: "Hospital B"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        hosp_id: "3",
        hosp_name: "Hospital C",
        is_available: true,
        schedule: [
            {
                schedule_id: "xx15",
                hospital_id: "3",
                day: 1,
                from_time: "15:00:00",
                to_time: "17:00:00",
                hospital_name: "Hospital C"
            },
            {
                schedule_id: "xx16",
                hospital_id: "3",
                day: 4,
                from_time: "15:00:00",
                to_time: "17:00:00",
                hospital_name: "Hospital C"
            },
            {
                schedule_id: "xx17",
                hospital_id: "3",
                day: 5,
                from_time: "15:00:00",
                to_time: "17:00:00",
                hospital_name: "Hospital C",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: if you notice the downvotes, they are probably because people want to see what you have tried so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `map` over the hospitals and for each one, `filter` out schedules of that hospital like so:

```
let dataNewHospital = dataHospital.availability.map(hospital => ({
  ...hospital,
  schedule: dataHospital.schedule.filter(schedule => schedule.hospital_id === hospital.hosp_id)
}));
```

The above solution is concise but not very effecient as it runs over the `schedule` array (which is the bigger array) for every hospital, where ideally it should run over it once. If you have large amount of data and you want a faster approach try this:

```
let scheduleByHospital = dataHospital.schedule.reduce((acc, schedule) => {
  acc[schedule.hospital_id] = acc[schedule.hospital_id] || [];
  acc[schedule.hospital_id].push(schedule);
  return acc;
}, Object.create(null));

let dataNewHospital = dataHospital.availability.map(hospital => ({
  ...hospital,
  schedule: scheduleByHospital[hospital.hosp_id] || []
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution:

```
dataHospital.availability.map(el => ({ 
     ...el , 
     schedule : dataHospital.schedule.filter( sc => sc.hospital_id == el.hosp_id) };
))
```

you map over the hospital, and inject to the same object (`{...el}` makes a copy of the object) a new property `schedule` with the related schedules with the same `hospital_id` of the current one

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
dataHospital.availability.reduce((result, availability) => {
  return [
    ...result,
    {
      ...availability,
      schedule: dataHospital.schedule.filter((schedule) => {
        return schedule.hospital_id === availability.hosp_id;
      })
    }
  ]
}, []);
```

Comment: as a side question, you are using `reduce` and not `map`? it's just curiosity

Comment: I initially thought it should end up in an object/hash ("grouped by id") instead of resulting in an array. If the result should be the array, `map` is probably the better fit here, true.

Comment: Ahah i only wants to know the reasoning behind, not saying which one is the best, btw, thank you

Comment: You can use [the concise body of arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body) since yours only have one statement in them

Comment: Thanks, I know about that. I like to always see a `return` statement in arrow functions that are split into multiple lines as I tripped over forgetting it in longer arrow functions where it was necessary too many times.

Comment: I think the array vs object result for a group by is subjective. I prefer an object of arrays, but some prefer an array of arrays. There are good arguments for both.